# Is my app.config working? Truncated data

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, config

This is my first WCF service project writing both client and server side. I'm from a Windows Forms background.
I think I've been having problems with packet/receive buffer size but I don't have a clue how to test whether my app.config is working correctly or what I've done wrong.

The client project's app.config is set as follows and it's testproj.exe.config reflects the contents correctly

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPulseWebService"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas
    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
    maxDepth="2147483647"
    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="blah"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPulseWebService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IPulseWebService" name="WSHttpBinding_IPulseWebService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhst" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My web service's webservice.dll.config contains the following service.serviceModel section

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPulseWebService"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas
         maxArrayLength="2147483647"
         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
         maxDepth="2147483647"
         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
         maxStringContentLength="2147483647" /> 
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPulseWebService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="SmartcentreWcfLib.PulseWebService">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://l0calhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/SmartcentreWcfLib/PulseWebService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <!-- Service Endpoints -->
      <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
      <endpoint  address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPulseWebService"
                 contract="SmartcentreWcfLib.IPulseWebService">
        <!-- 
            Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
            identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
            automatically.
        -->
        <identity>
          <dns value="l0calhost" />
        </identity>

      </endpoint>
      <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
      <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
      <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
        set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
        set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
        to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In my server side wcf dll, I have the following function just as a test to return some rows of data. Each row is a set of key/value pairs stored in an Dictionary. Each object should be a simple byte[] or variable type.

```
  List<IDictionary<string, object>> IAuditV1.ReadAuditForStaffMember(long staffId, DateTime startDate, 
    DateTime endDate, Int32 recordCount)
  {
      List<TableAdminAudit> tempResult = DatabaseInterface.Instance.AuditQueries.ReadAdminAudit(staffId, startDate,
        endDate, recordCount);
      return tempResult.Select(record => record.PrepareForWebInterface()).Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>().ToList();
  }// function
```

In my client application I am running the following loop, which simply increments the number of received records.

```
      Int32 totalRecords = 0;
      while (true)
      {
        results = client.ReadAuditForStaffMember(1, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now, totalRecords);
        totalRecords += 10; //results.Length;
        if (totalRecords == 0) break;
      }
```

On the 3rd loop when the returned buffer reaches 30 records in size I receive the following error message.
I looked up the error and forums suggested it relates to the connection closing before the whole data had been received so change the various buffer sizes etc. As you can see from my config files, I've upped all the values I'm aware of to 2147483647 but it's not worked.
So I don't know where to go from here. Can anybody help please?

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to blah2/Design_Time_Addresses/SmartcentreWcfLib/PulseWebService/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at WcfTester.ServiceReference1.IPulseWebService.ReadAuditForStaffMember(Int64 staffId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Int32 startIndex)
       at WcfTester.ServiceReference1.PulseWebServiceClient.ReadAuditForStaffMember(Int64 staffId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Int32 startIndex) in W:\Projects\pulse.smartcentre.root\pulse.smartcentre\WcfTester\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 481
       at WcfTester.Program.Main(String[] args) in W:\Projects\pulse.smartcentre.root\pulse.smartcentre\WcfTester\Program.cs:line 40
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       InnerException: System.IO.IOException
            HResult=-2146232800
            Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
                 at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
                 at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
            InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
                 HResult=-2147467259
                 Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                 Source=System
                 ErrorCode=10054
                 NativeErrorCode=10054
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
                 InnerException:**
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The file `something.dll.config` is *never* used. You need to copy those settings into the web.config or servicehost.exe.config file.

This is how .NET has worked since Day 1, and is not specific to WCF. Consider that a given DLL can be used by multiple "executables", and each of these may have different settings for the DLL.

Comment: Where can I find web.config or servicehost.exe.config? They're not in the \bin\debug directories.

Comment: Web.config will be in the root of the IIS application that is hosting the service. "servicehost.exe.config" would be if you were self-hosting.

Comment: This is where I'm confused. I created a WCF Library project, NOT a WCF application. Probably following an example somewhere. If I run that, VS opens a WCF test client. Looking at my c:\inetpub I see nothing there. I'm not understanding what's going on in background.